# How do I restart a program on ubuntu without using loops and crontab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, cron, restart

I have a program running on ubuntu server, I want to restart it if it gets terminated for some reason, I did try an infinite loop however it is a very processor hungry task and using crontab is also not quite feasible as I don't want to run my program as root. What other option I can look for, please help.

Comment: Put it to `/etc/inittab`. Just follow how getty starts as the example.

Comment: ok, but how soon will it restart the program?

Comment: for details you should read man. I may assume immediately as the process exits. Most probably there is also some additional logic to prevent spin loops or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, will try

Comment: I tried it on CentOS and it seem to be working however I can't find the inittab file in ubuntu

Comment: Do you have `/etc/init` or `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` or something similar? I guess in Ubuntu they have tuned this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try supervisor.
If you are using Debian/Ubuntu,you are install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

By edit the config file at “/etc/supervisor/conf.d” like this：

```
[program:app]
command= the command you want run
directory= the directory
user= the user
```

The supervisor will keep the program runing, and if the program die, supervisor will auto restart it

Comment: Many thanks will try these and will reply back with the results